# Counting the number of results from a large database

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I got a two database tables, one has 165 entries. For each of those, I got to browse the 1-million-entry table and see how many times is each of those 165 entries mentioned.

"odds_provider" has 165 entries, "bettingoffer" has a million entries.

```
    $SQL = "SELECT
    odds_provider.id AS id,
    odds_provider.name AS name,
    COUNT(bettingoffer.odds_providerFK) AS betcount
    FROM odds_provider
    INNER JOIN
    bettingoffer
    ON bettingoffer.odds_providerFK = odds_provider.id
    WHERE 
    odds_provider.active = 'yes'
    GROUP BY
    odds_provider.id,
    odds_provider.name
    ORDER BY betcount DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $db_field['id'] , " " , $db_field['name'] , " " , $db_field['betcount'] , "</BR>";
    }
```

It does what's intended but it takes forever. Is there a faster way?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the 2 tables? Can you try at the MySQL prompt (or through PHPMyAdmin and tell us the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` output?

Comment: how many distinct odds_providerFK are there in the bettingoffer table, are there many inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should be faster, especially if there not many inactive ids.

```
SELECT id, name, betcount
FROM (
  SELECT
    odds_providerFK as id,
    COUNT(*) as betcount
  FROM bettingoffer
  WHERE active = 'yes'
  GROUP BY odds_providerFK
  ORDER BY betcount DESC) as counts
USING (id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to join the two tables using SQL. It would be best to not do a COUNT(*) though.  You can get better performance by specifying the specific column you would want to count.

```
SELECT
  op.id,
  op.name,
  COUNT(bo.odds_providerFK) AS bet_offering_count
FROM
 odds_provider op
 INNER JOIN
 bettingoffer bo
  ON bo.odds_providerFK = op.id
 WHERE 
  op.active = 'yes'
GROUP BY
  op.id,
  op.name
```

Comment: Actually, in MYSQL `COUNT(*)` is usually faster than `COUNT(column)`.

Comment: The COUNT(*) will be much faster for MyISAM tables because it caches the column count. InnoDB tables do not cache the row count so the COUNT(*) will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in much better way using SQL Join queries. You don't have to search the 2nd table for each individual record in 1st table. You can establish a JOIN relationship between the tables.

It would be more helpful if you would have pasted the schema definition of both of your tables, but in general this is how JOIN queries works.

Kindly [refer to these tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) about how JOIN queries work.

Comment: INNER JOIN is not a problem, I know how to do it. The problem is getting the counted results as an array. This would be the code for join: INNER JOIN bettingoffer ON bettingoffer.odds_providerFK = odds_provider.id

Comment: what is your goal? do you want to find how many entries are there in your 2nd table for each entry in your 1st table?

Comment: the type of JOIN you should use will depend on your goal

Comment: do a LEFT JOIN on bettingoffer.odds_providerFK=odds_provider.id

Comment: use a left join as i mentioned. LEFT JOIN on bettingoffer.odds_providerFK=odds_provider.id

Comment: The join is not a problem. Counting the results is.